# How to import data to elasticsearch using golang

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I am using `gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5` and I am trying to import data from a json file to elasticsearch DB using golang. This is my code

```
package main

import(
    "gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "log"
    "os"
    "encoding/json"
)

type people struct{
    Firstname string `json:"firstname"`
    Lastname string `json:"lastname"`
    Institution string `json:"institution"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
}

type item struct{
    Id string `json:"id"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Journal  string `json:"journal"`
    Volume int `json:"volume"`
    Number int `json:"number"`
    Pages string `json:"pages"`
    Year int `json:"year"`
    Authors []people `json:"authors"`
    Abstract string `json:"abstract"`
    Link string `json:"link"`
    Keywords []string `json:"keywords"`
    Body string `json:"body"`
}

var client *elastic.Client
var err error
func init(){
    client,err = elastic.NewClient()
    if err!=nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    var data []item

    file,err := os.Open("data.json")
    if err!=nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    jsonDeocder :=  json.NewDecoder(file)
    if err := jsonDeocder.Decode(&data); err!=nil{
        log.Fatal("Decode: ",err)
    }

    bulkIndex("library","article",data)
}

func bulkIndex(index string,typ string ,data []item){
    ctx := context.Background()
    for _,item := range data{
        _,err := client.Index().Index(index).Type(typ).BodyJson(item).Do(ctx)   
        if err !=nil{
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }   
}
```

The package documentation is huge and I am not sure if I have gone the right way. This compiles fine but after running this, when I check my elasticsearch DB on kibana using `GET /library/article/575084573a2404eec25acdcd?pretty` (`575084573a2404eec25acdcd` is the correct id from my json file), I am getting the following response

```
{
  "_index": "library",
  "_type": "article",
  "_id": "575084573a2404eec25acdcd",
  "found": false
}
```

How do I import my data?

EDIT: This is what I get on doing `GET /library?pretty` on kibana

```
{
  "library": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "article": {
        "properties": {
          "abstract": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "authors": {
            "properties": {
              "email": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "firstname": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "institution": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "lastname": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "body": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "journal": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "keywords": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "link": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "number": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "pages": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "volume": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "year": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1486063182258",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "_SLeDWb4QPinFcSwOCUtCw",
        "version": {
          "created": "5020099"
        },
        "provided_name": "library"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not see you setting up a url for your elasticsearch cluster upon initialization of the elastic client. Might that be the problem?

Comment: https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5 says that if Elasticsearch is running on `localhost:9200` then there is no need to specify the address for `NewClient()`

Comment: Good. Just checking.

Comment: Is `_,err := client.Index().Index(index).Type(typ).BodyJson(item).Do(ctx)` in function `bulkIndex` right for doing what I am trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I'm starting to suspect that because you've already decoded the json, you might be better served by replacing .BodyJson(item) with .Doc(item)

Comment: It says `client.Index().Index(index).Type(typ).Doc undefined (type *elastic.IndexService has no field or method Doc)` .

Comment: I apologize that's available in the search api only probably.

Comment: I have updated the description with the response I get on doing a GET for library in elasticsearch DB. It shows the structure in which my json data is but there is no data, How is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got it. I should have specified the Id for my item as well instead of just specifying the index and type.

The correct statement should be

```
_,err := client.Index().Index(index).Type(typ).Id(item.Id).BodyJson(item).Do(ctx)
```

Comment: good to know, I had the Id set as well but assumed elasticsearch would automatically do that for us if not set

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. :D